# How to know what code inside iframe from other web site with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I load iframe from other site (google adsense ad):

```
<iframe src="some google address" ...></iframe>
```

I need to know what is inside this frame, particularly how much tags `a` inside.

I can't load iframe body with `contentDocument` method(because of private policy):

```
var frame= element.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
var body = frame.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
```

Any idea how to do so?

Comment: Programmatically or manually?

Comment: Programmatically, of course.

Comment: Yeah, I figured, Pretty much what @AlexeiLevenkov said.

Answer (score 0):

You can't write JavaScript code on your page that will provide information about content of IFrame on other domain as same origin policy prevents such access.

You may *try* to send initial url to your server and perform HTML parsing there, but there is no guarantees that there is no other navigation or JavaScript running on that page. Again with some creativity you can match rendering on server to get some information matching browser's behavior - but you will not be able to match 100% as your server side code will not have a way to pass the same cookies browsers has.